# Prove that $\sum_{n = 1}^{n = s} n^2 \ne \sum_{n = t}^{n = u} n^2$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation

where $t > s$ and $s,t,u,n$ are positive integers. The inequality is my claim. I arrived at this as I was tinkering with stuff. I tried various things but no luck.

Comment: why are you restricting the number of terms to two on both sides? It is obvious that $u-t+1 < s$. Beyond that what can you say?

Comment: @UddeshyaSingh $s-1$ may be $>u-t$. So you could have something like $1+4+9+16+36$ versus $49$. There not equal, but are there cases for other $s,t,u$ where there's an equality.

Comment: Good point. Apologies @sku

Comment: @sku Suggest you come up with a function $f$ for summation of squares (it'll be a cubic polynomial). Then see what $f(s) - f(u) +f(t-1)$ looks like when it is fully expanded.

Comment: By the way, if $(s,t,u)=(a,b,c)$ is  solution with $1<t\leq s$ then $(s,t,u)=(b-1,a,c)$ is a solution with with $s<t$.

Answer (score 11):

The claim is not true: if $s=24$ and $t=u=70$ then
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{24}n^2=4900=70^2 $$

This is the only solution for $s<t=u$: see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CannonballProblem.html).

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. Any known solutions for $u > t$?

Comment: I don't know of any off the top of my head. It wouldn't be too hard to write a program to look for them.

Answer (score 6):

Brute force found an example with $(s,t,u)=(3535,45871,45877)$.

After this initial solution, I expanded my search, and found a lot more.

The smallest $s$ I've found is $(s,t,u)=(42,46,55)$.

From the data, I inferred two infinite set of solutions:

$$(s,t,u)=(12d^2(d-1)+d,24d^4-36d^3+12d^2+d,24d^4-36d^3+12d^2+2d-1)$$

and:

$$(s,t,u)=(12d^2(d+1)+d-1,24 d^4 + 36 d^3 + 12 d^2 - 2 d ,24 d^4 + 36 d^3 + 12 d^2 - d-1)$$
With Wolfram Alpha, I've verified these answers always work.

Then there are occasionally other "exceptional" cases outside these patterns.

---

You want:

$$\frac{s(s+1)(2s+1)}{6}=\frac{u(u+1)(2u+1)}6-\frac{t(t-1)(2t-1)}{6}$$

or, for $p(x)=x(x+1)(2x+1)=2x^3+3x^2+x$:

$$p(s)=p(u)-p(t-1)$$

If $a=t-1$ and $d=u-(t-1)$ then:

$$\begin{align}p(u)-p(t-1)&=p(a+d)-p(a)=p'(a)d+\frac{1}{2}p''(a)d^2+\frac{1}6p'''(a)d^3\\
&=(6a^2+6a+1)d+(6a+3)d^2+2d^3\\
&=(6d)a^2+6(d^2+d)a+p(d)\end{align}$$

So $6d\mid p(s)-p(d)$, and then you need a solution to:

$$a^2+(d+1)a-\frac{p(s)-p(d)}{6d}=0$$

So you need $(d+1)^2+4\frac{p(s)-p(d)}{6d}$ to be a perfect square.

My instinct is to try $d=7$, since $d=1$ is known to have a solution, and $7\equiv 1\pmod{6}$. Then $p(d)=840,$ and you:
$$8^2+\frac{2}{21}(p(s)-840)=\frac{2p(s)}{21}-16$$

I brute forced with a python script from there, assuming $s$ was a multiple of $d=7$.

After finding that first example, I tried lots of different values of $d$, checking values of $s$ up to $1,000,000.$

Here's a bunch more solutions. It looks like there are two solutions for each $d>1$ that have $s$ growing roughly exponentially in $d$, and for some $d$, there are smaller values $s$.

```
d=2
(s,t,u)=(50, 146, 147)
(s,t,u)=(145, 716, 717)
d=3
(s,t,u)=(219, 1083, 1085)
(s,t,u)=(434, 3018, 3020)
d=4
(s,t,u)=(580, 4036, 4039)
(s,t,u)=(963, 8632, 8635)
d=5
(s,t,u)=(1205, 10805, 10809)
(s,t,u)=(1804, 19790, 19794)
d=6
(s,t,u)=(2166, 23766, 23771)
(s,t,u)=(3029, 39300, 39305)
d=7
(s,t,u)=(136, 345, 351)
(s,t,u)=(3535, 45871, 45877)
(s,t,u)=(4710, 70546, 70552)
d=8
(s,t,u)=(5384, 80648, 80655)
(s,t,u)=(6919, 117488, 117495)
d=9
(s,t,u)=(7785, 132201, 132209)
(s,t,u)=(9728, 184662, 184670)
d=10
(s,t,u)=(42, 46, 55)
(s,t,u)=(10810, 205210, 205219)
(s,t,u)=(13209, 277180, 277189)
d=11
(s,t,u)=(417, 1480, 1490)
(s,t,u)=(14531, 304931, 304941)
(s,t,u)=(17434, 400730, 400740)
d=12
(s,t,u)=(124, 226, 237)
(s,t,u)=(19020, 437196, 437207)
(s,t,u)=(22475, 561576, 561587)
d=13
(s,t,u)=(24349, 608413, 608425)
(s,t,u)=(28404, 766558, 766570)
d=14
(s,t,u)=(126, 213, 226)
(s,t,u)=(189, 396, 409)
(s,t,u)=(8981, 131334, 131347)
(s,t,u)=(30590, 825566, 825579)
(s,t,u)=(35293, 1023092, 1023105)
d=15
(s,t,u)=(37815, 1096215, 1096229)
(s,t,u)=(43214, 1339170, 1339184)
d=16
(s,t,u)=(46096, 1428496, 1428511)
(s,t,u)=(52239, 1723360, 1723375)
d=17
(s,t,u)=(55505, 1831121, 1831137)
(s,t,u)=(62440, 2184806, 2184822)
d=18
(s,t,u)=(66114, 2313378, 2313395)
(s,t,u)=(73889, 2733228, 2733245)
d=19
(s,t,u)=(77995, 2885131, 2885149)
(s,t,u)=(86658, 3378922, 3378940)
d=20
(s,t,u)=(91220, 3556820, 3556839)
(s,t,u)=(100819, 4132760, 4132779)
d=21
(s,t,u)=(105861, 4339461, 4339481)
(s,t,u)=(116444, 5006190, 5006210)
d=22
(s,t,u)=(121990, 5244646, 5244667)
(s,t,u)=(133605, 6011236, 6011257)
d=23
(s,t,u)=(139679, 6284543, 6284565)
(s,t,u)=(152374, 7160498, 7160520)
d=24
(s,t,u)=(375, 846, 869)
(s,t,u)=(159000, 7471896, 7471919)
(s,t,u)=(172823, 8467152, 8467175)
d=25
(s,t,u)=(399, 910, 934)
(s,t,u)=(5775, 50670, 50694)
(s,t,u)=(180025, 8820025, 8820049)
(s,t,u)=(195024, 9944950, 9944974)
d=26
(s,t,u)=(202826, 10342826, 10342851)
(s,t,u)=(219049, 11608220, 11608245)
d=27
(s,t,u)=(227475, 12054771, 12054797)
(s,t,u)=(244970, 13471866, 13471892)
d=28
(s,t,u)=(254044, 13970908, 13970935)
(s,t,u)=(272859, 15551368, 15551395)
d=29
(s,t,u)=(282605, 16106861, 16106889)
(s,t,u)=(302788, 17862782, 17862810)
d=30
(s,t,u)=(313230, 18478830, 18478859)
(s,t,u)=(334829, 20422740, 20422769)
d=31
(s,t,u)=(345991, 21103591, 21103621)
(s,t,u)=(369054, 23248450, 23248480)
d=32
(s,t,u)=(380960, 23998496, 23998527)
(s,t,u)=(405535, 26357696, 26357727)
d=33
(s,t,u)=(418209, 27181473, 27181505)
(s,t,u)=(444344, 29768838, 29768870)
d=34
(s,t,u)=(457810, 30671026, 30671059)
(s,t,u)=(485553, 33500812, 33500845)
d=35
(s,t,u)=(499835, 34486235, 34486269)
(s,t,u)=(529234, 37573130, 37573164)
d=36
(s,t,u)=(544356, 38646756, 38646791)
(s,t,u)=(575459, 42005880, 42005915)
d=37
(s,t,u)=(591445, 43172821, 43172857)
(s,t,u)=(624300, 46819726, 46819762)
d=38
(s,t,u)=(5757, 40898, 40935)
(s,t,u)=(641174, 48085238, 48085275)
(s,t,u)=(675829, 52035908, 52035945)
d=39
(s,t,u)=(693615, 53405391, 53405429)
(s,t,u)=(730118, 57676242, 57676280)
d=40
(s,t,u)=(748840, 59155240, 59155279)
(s,t,u)=(787239, 63763120, 63763159)
```

If I were to try to prove there is a solution for every $d$, I'd try to understand those pairs. The smaller $s$ for each pair seems to be divisible by $d$.

A little tinkering sees that the smaller value of $s$ for each pair is $s=12d^2(d-1)+d$.

Then a bit of number crunching gets the two infinite sets of solutions for each $d$.

It is possible that for each $d$ that there are only finitely many solutions.

Comment: [+1] Very thorough answer !

Answer (score 0):

I hope You are familiar with $$\sum_{r=1} ^n n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Now, Your LHS:
$$\frac{s(s+1)(2s+1)}{6}$$

For your RHS: Number of terms=$u-t$ provided $u \neq t$ 
$$\text{Sum till u }-\text{Sum till t }$$
$$\frac{u(u+1)(2u+1)}{6}-\frac{t(t+1)(2t+1)}{6}$$
$$\frac{(u-t)[(2(u^2+t^2+ut)+3(u+t)+1]}{6}$$

We know that $t>s$. Here, we can see that this RHS (maybe) greater than LHS. BUT only when $u \neq t$.

Case II: $u=t$

Take s from $1$ to $50$:
0
1
5
14
30
55
91
140
204
285
385
506
650
819
1015
1240
1496
1785
2109
2470
2870
3311
3795
4324
**4900**
5525
6201
6930
7714
8555
9455
10416
11440
12529
13685
14910
16206
17575
19019
20540
22140
23821
25585
27434
29370
31395
33511
35720
38024
40425

That $4900$ is the counter example to your claim when $u=t=70$ {Due Credits to @carmicheal561 }

Comment: You want to subtract the sum til t-1, and the number of terms is $u-(t-1)$. It's not clear what you are saying, though, about the first case.